# Inserting data to MySQL database from droplist

Tags: php

i have code to insert values into mysql database. but the problem doesn't insert anything.

what i want is if user select from droplist table1. value inserting into table1 and son for table2.

my html code

```
 <html>
 <body>

 <form method="post" action="update.php">
 <input type="txt" name="name"/>
 <select name="tables">
 <option value="table1">table1</option>
 <option value="table2">table2</option>
 <option value="table3">table3</option>
 <option value="table4">table4</option>
 </select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit Pick" />

</body>
</html>
```

my php code

```
<?php


$table =$_POST['tables'];
$name =$_POST['name'];

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","sqldata","sqldata","accounts");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="INSERT INTO $table (name)
VALUES
('$_POST[name]')";



echo ".$table.$name";

?>
```

Comment: ... you never insert anything. You just create the SQL string and... nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You never actually run the query.  After you define $sql, execute it.

```
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Also of note, hopefully this is only test code.  You must NEVER EVER take raw input from a request without passing it through something like `mysqli_escape_string`.

Comment: im getting this error : Warning: mysqli_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /var/www/html/download/update.php on line 4

Warning: mysqli_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /var/www/html/download/update.php on line 5
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(name) VALUES ('mike')' at line 1

Comment: You need `mysqli_escape_string ( $con ,$name);`  Check the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php  (note that `mysqli_escape_string` is an alias for `mysqli_real_escape_string`... they're identical except for the name).

Comment: im getting again error : Notice: Undefined variable: con in /var/www/html/download/update.php on line 5

Warning: mysqli_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /var/www/html/download/update.php on line 5

Answer (score 0):

You code contains some errors. Once you never call `mysqli_query` to send the SQL to the server. In addition there's an error in your sql string. If you want to insert an array's value, you have to use brackets: `{$_POST[name]}`. Even better is the use of `mysqli_escape_string`. So your code should look like this:

```
$name = mysqli_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);

$sql="INSERT INTO $table (name)
VALUES
('$name')"

mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Comment: im getting this error:Warning: mysqli_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /var/www/html/download/update.php on line 4

Warning: mysqli_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /var/www/html/download/update.php on line 5
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(name) VALUES ('mike')' at line 1

Comment: I've edited the code to pass `$con` as a paramter to `mysqli_escape_string`